# How to make Datebox Jquery Mobile Input field clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, datebox

I have two date fields. Field 2 works fine. Clicking anywhere on the input type date for second fields opens the calendar. But the same is not working for first date field. When I click on the calendar icon for date field it opens the calendar but I want that calendar should pop up when I click anywhere on the date field for field 1 as well.
Why does it works for the second field but not for the first field.

Also the default date is not getting set to todays date.

http://jsfiddle.net/KJ4e5/3/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="doc">
<table>
<tr>
                        <td>

                         <input name="date1" id="date1" type="date"  data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox","dateFieldOrder":["d","m","y"], "useNewStyle":true,"overrideDateFormat": "%d/%m/%Y", "afterToday":true}' />
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <input name="date2" id="date2" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox","dateFieldOrder":["d","m","y"], "useNewStyle":true,"overrideDateFormat": "%d/%m/%Y", "afterToday":true}'/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
</table>
        </div></body>
```

//JS

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#doc", function() { 
    var defaultPickerValue = new Date();
    var today = defaultPickerValue.getDate() + "/" + (defaultPickerValue.getMonth()+1) + "/" + defaultPickerValue.getFullYear();

     $('#date1').val(today);
     $('#date2').val(today);

$('#date1').on('change', function() {
        if ( $('#date2')) {
            $('#date2').val($('#date1').val());
              var temp = new Date();
              var start = $('#date1').datebox('getTheDate');
              var diff = parseInt((start - temp) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ));
              diffstrt = (diff * -1)-1; 
            $("#date2").datebox("option", {
                "minDays": diffstrt
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain why the 2 boxes act differently, but if you explicitly assign the useFocus option to the boxes, they will both work:

```
<input name="date1" id="date1" type="date" data-role="datebox" 
    data-options='{"mode": "calbox","dateFieldOrder":["d","m","y"], 
                   "useNewStyle":true, "overrideDateFormat": "%d/%m/%Y",
                   "afterToday":true, "centerHoriz": true, "useFocus": true}' />
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/KJ4e5/5/)**

In the fiddle I have also changed your script a little. With the datebox you can set the dates as follows:

```
var defaultPickerValue = new Date();
$('#date1').datebox('setTheDate', defaultPickerValue).trigger('datebox', {'method':'doset'});


$('#date1').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#date2')) {
        var temp = new Date();
        var start = $('#date1').datebox('getTheDate');
        $('#date2').datebox('setTheDate', start).trigger('datebox', {'method':'doset'});
        var diff = parseInt((start - temp) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        diffstrt = (diff * -1) - 1;
        $("#date2").datebox("option", {
            "minDays": diffstrt
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much...This was of great help :)

Comment: One more question : Even when I select a particular date in the calendar, todays date is always shown highlighted. I have to remove it. The default date has css class  "ui-btn-b" applied on it by default.How do I ensure only one of the date has that class applied on it at a time?

Comment: @user1502901, add the option: "themeDateToday": false. Here is an updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/KJ4e5/8/